Looking for the name on a fairy movie
I was thinking about a movie I saw a little time ago but I just could't remember the name,  It's about a father that is doing research on fairies and his daughter didn't believe in that. 
One day she was out in the woods (or something like that) and she saw one of the fairies. The queen fairy had almost died and she shrunk the human girl down to the fairy size so she can help the queen live and fight some monsters who is trying to destroy the fairy city.
She meets a guy and she falls in love with him. The human girls father has to help her to get back to human size again and at the end she has to make a choice... either to stay with the fairies and live with the guy she loves or she could go back to human size again and never return to fairy size. 
At the end, "her work is done" and she is being sucked back to the normal world but the guy/boyfriend takes his arms around her and kisses her. She gets sucked back to human and the only way they can communicate with each other is by a screen and camera that her father set up both in the woods and in his house. 
They communicate and they are still together.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Descriptions or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

Epic 2013 

A teenager finds herself transported to a deep forest setting where a battle between the forces of good and the forces of evil is taking place. She bands together with a rag-tag group of characters in order to save their world -- and ours.




